# Multiple instances of one UIImageView on-screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sdk

I am making a game where bullets are involved. Its a machine gun, so there will be more than one bullet on the screen at the same time. How to I write the code for the properties and actions of one bullet and apply that to all of them, like multiple instances of the one bullet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point to making a game is the concept of *sprite*, i.e., a light-weight object that has a graphical representation and that you can move around (managing collisions, etc).

You could try to implement sprites on top of CALayers, using Core Animation, or you might decide to use a game framework like [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).

For the first approach have a look at [this short tutorial](http://www.angryfishstudios.com/2011/04/sprites-using-only-coreanimation/). This could also help you if you want to implement your sprites using UIImageViews, although you have to keep in mind that CALayer are light-weight, UIView are not, so if you plan to have many of them that could make a difference.

As to the question of replicating the bullet, basically the key suggestion would be using some form of caching, so that you do not end up replicating the same image in memory multiple times. A very basic caching mechanism is available with the `UIImage` class if you use the convenience constructor `imageNamed`.

Again, if you plan to make a full fledged game with a good performance (say 40-60 fps), the best suggestion is using Cocos2D, which will offer you all the power of Open GL graphics wrapped in a simple interface.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried subclassing `UIImageView`? That way you can have a function `createBullet` that creates a subclassed `UIImageView` and adds it to the screen, and in the subclass it can contain functions and properties for animating etc...